# Would selenium end to end test run faster if the test were written in Java or in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Trying to decide which way to go for e2e tests Selenium tests written in Java or Javascript? Which would be faster(time tests take to run) which would be easier to maintain?

Comment: Java and Javascript have very little in common except the word 'java'. Scrips are quicker to get up and running and good if you are changing your code often. If it is an app you are building I would go Java but it can have a startup lag. For testing purposes my advice is scripting

Comment: Possibly `JavaScript` though I don't have any data to prove as of now.

Comment: It will be the same. The cost on the client side is insignificant. You should use the language that you and your team are the most comfortable to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which would be faster can only be answered by a benchmark.

I think the speed difference of java or javascript will be negligible compared to the overhead of selenium and the website itself. Even if one proves to be milliseconds faster than the other, what does it matter if a single test takes seconds from end to end. To make matters worse selenium run times typically vary greatly because of all the components involved.

I can imagine speed difference of the language becoming noticeable IF you have a very special use case like thousands of microtests and/or the webserver is highly optimized for micropayloads. But as said: there is no universal answer. You must benchmark.

Easier to maintain would be the language you (and your team) are more comfortable with.

If you are equaly comfortable with both languages, and there are no other factors to base the decision on, then flip a coin. Or write some of the more complicated tests in both languages and maintain them for some time. Then decide based on the experience of maintaining them.